# Python: mapping a list of lists onto a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

If I have a list like this

```
l=[[(1, 2), (1, 3)], [(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(1, 3), (2, 3)]]
```

and a dictionary like this

```
d={(1, 2): 3.61, (1, 3): 5.0, (2, 3): 6.0}
```

and I want to produce a list of lists that contains the values in `d` associated with the keys that appear in `l`, like this

```
newlist=[[3.61,5.0],[3.61,6.0],[5.0,6.0]]
```

How could I do it?

My attempt is

```
newlist=[v for k, v in d.items() if l[[i]]==k for i in l]
```

but this returns

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Comment: `[[d[y] for y in x] for x in l]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because first of all the result should be a *list of lists*: your list comprehension will (if it would work) construct a list of values.

Furthermore it would loop *only once* over the dictionary (since that is the left `for` loop).

You can do this less *error-prone* and more efficient with:

```
newlist = [[d[x] for x in li] for li in l]
```

This will work given **all tuples are keys in the dictionary `d`**. If that is not the case, you can use `.get(..)` and specify a *default value* (for instance `None`):

```
newlist = [[d.get(x,None) for x in li] for li in l]
```